# Sending an email based on two cell inputs in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm fairly new here so apologies for asking a possibly stupid question.

I'm trying to get Google Sheets to send an email based on the information in columns B and O

Here is my code thus far...

```
function confirmationEmail(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(BIKE2)
  var orderNumber = e.values[2];
  var subject = "Order is Ready to be Confirmed";
  var body = "An order from the bike shop is ready to be confirmed! Order Number: " + orderNumber;
  if (e.values[14] == NOT NULL);
  if (e.values[1] == 'Order Entry');
 MailApp.sendEmail("dylan.bassett@activesportsinc.com", subject, body)
}
```

Currently when I try to run the code I get an error saying:

"Missing ) after condition. (line 6, file "Confirmation Emails")"

I'm not sure how far off I am here, I was able to get a similar code to work without a condition but things got dicey when I started trying to tell it when to do things.

Any help is appreciated! I'm sure this is a rookie problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume your using a form Submit. I don't send much email so not sure about the syntax for that but BIKE2 needs to be in quotes and the semicolons after the if's are not wanted.  So try this.

```
function confirmationEmail(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet('BIKE2')
  var orderNumber = e.values[2];
  var subject = "Order is Ready to be Confirmed";
  var body = "An order from the bike shop is ready to be confirmed! Order Number: " + orderNumber;
  if (e.values[14] && e.values[1] == 'Order Entry')
  {
    MailApp.sendEmail("dylan.bassett@activesportsinc.com", subject, body);
  }
}
```